ValueError: Layer 'dense' expected 1 input(s). Received 2 instead
I am trying to train a VGG16 model to recognize dog breeds. The problem is that I can't load the model after training the it. I keep getting this error: ValueError: Layer 'dense' expected 1 input(s). Received 2 instead
from keras.src.legacy.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.src.saving import load_model
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.applications import VGG16
from keras import layers, models

def load_and_crop_image(image_path, annotation_path, save_dir='cropped_images'):

    # Parse the XML file for bounding box
    tree = ET.parse(annotation_path)
    root = tree.getroot()
    bndbox = root.find(".//object/bndbox")
    xmin = int(bndbox.find('xmin').text)
    ymin = int(bndbox.find('ymin').text)
    xmax = int(bndbox.find('xmax').text)
    ymax = int(bndbox.find('ymax').text)

    # Load and crop the image
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    cropped_image = image.crop((xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax))
    cropped_image_resized = cropped_image.resize((224, 224))  # Resize to fit VGG16 input size

    if not os.path.exists(save_dir):
        os.makedirs(save_dir)

    image_file_name = os.path.basename(image_path)
    save_path = os.path.join(save_dir, image_file_name)

    # cropped_image_resized.save(save_path)

    # print(f"Saving cropped image to: {save_path}")

    return np.array(cropped_image_resized)


def load_dataset(images_dir, annotations_dir):
    images = []
    labels = []

    for breed in os.listdir(annotations_dir):
        breed_annotations_dir = os.path.join(annotations_dir, breed)
        breed_images_dir = os.path.join(images_dir, breed)

        for annotation_file in os.listdir(breed_annotations_dir):
            annotation_path = os.path.join(breed_annotations_dir, annotation_file)
            image_file_name = annotation_file.split('.')[0] + '.jpg'
            image_path = os.path.join(breed_images_dir, image_file_name)

            if os.path.exists(image_path):
                image = load_and_crop_image(image_path, annotation_path)
                images.append(image)

                labels.append(breed)

    return np.array(images), np.array(labels)

images_dir = 'images'
annotations_dir = 'annotations'
images, labels = load_dataset(images_dir, annotations_dir)

# Encode labels
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoded_labels = label_encoder.fit_transform(labels)
categorical_labels = to_categorical(encoded_labels)

def create_model(num_classes):
    base_model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
    base_model.trainable = False  # Freeze base model

    model = models.Sequential([
        base_model,
        layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
        layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'),
        layers.Dropout(0.5),
        layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')
    ])

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model


model = create_model(num_classes=categorical_labels.shape[1])

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255,
                             validation_split=0.1,
                             rotation_range=10,
                             width_shift_range=0.1,
                             height_shift_range=0.1,
                             shear_range=0.1,
                             zoom_range=0.1,
                             horizontal_flip=True,
                             vertical_flip=True
                             )
train_generator = datagen.flow(images, categorical_labels, batch_size=32, subset='training')
validation_generator = datagen.flow(images, categorical_labels, batch_size=32, subset='validation')




history = model.fit(train_generator, epochs=1, validation_data=validation_generator)

model.save('dog_breed_classifier.keras', overwrite=True)

print("Model saved successfully.")

try:
    model = load_model('dog_breed_classifier.keras')
    print("Model loaded successfully.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred while loading the model: {e}")

If I comment out this line history = model.fit(train_generator, epochs=1, validation_data=validation_generator) then the model is loaded succesfully.
If I save and load the model before model.fit(...) then I get the same error.

Is it possible that in your model you defined 2 layers.Dense(...)? What happens if you remove one of them?

If i delete the 1st dense layer i get this: ValueError: Arguments target and output must have the same shape. Received: target.shape=(None, 10), output.shape=(None, 1024)
If i delete the 2nd i get the same error as in my post.

this happens also for me. check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79278645/18346212
